# Where to download Apache FOP?

Tags: apache-fop, altova

I've recently installed Altova MissionKit 2012 to start working with XML-Spy to create style sheets and so on.  The way I understand it, and correct me if I'm wrong, but I need **Apache FOP** to output my XSL-FO to PDF?

I've been googling around and I'm having some trouble finding out where I can download it? Any advice would greatly be appreciated!

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://xmlgraphics.apache.org/fop/download.html

Comment: Thanks chinna_82, how exactly do I install this? (I'm new at this, sorry...)

Comment: at the bottom of the page you can see Archive Download..click on binaries or source...and download

Answer (score 1):

Altova has a link to download Apache FOP on their site, too: http://www.altova.com/components_processors.html